# SFML Segmentation Fault when using VBOs?

Tags: opengl, rendering

I'm trying to follow along with the [gltut](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Basics/Tut01%20Following%20the%20Data.html) tutorials and for some reason when I call GLDrawArrays my program segmentation faults. I've been looking at the state of my application with the Mac OpenGL Profiler and Googling and I can't seem to figure out why it isn't working. I may have missed setting some OpenGL state somewhere.

My code is [here](https://gist.github.com/1833181), it segfaults on line 32. If I don't call `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);` and the respective `glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);` it compiles and runs, but I get no rendering, which is what I would expect given my limited OpenGL knowledge.

Comment: do you link SFML as static or dynamic? the default build is for dynamic linking, when trying to link it as static, you'll get segmentation fault after exiting drawing functions, don't quote me on this, though, i'm no expert, i just had a similar issue and that was the problem

Comment: I link it dynamically. I can do immediate mode drawing just fine.

Comment: Is it because you're trying to draw a triangle with two vertices?

Comment: I guess I may have misunderstood how glDrawArrays works, but even if I try to draw two vertices it segfaults. I'll add that on my Mac it segfaults trying to read memory address `0x00000000`. For some reason on my linux machine gdb can't get a backtrace, complaining `Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)`.

Comment: Do you mean "even if I try to draw three vertices it segfaults"? Triangles have three vertices :P

Comment: Well whoops, yeah, I meant three.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you're taking a tutorial meant to teach modern, shader-based techniques, and are adapting it to fixed-function rendering? Doesn't that kinda defeat the whole point the tutorial's trying to get across?

Comment: I didn't realize that was what I was doing, but reading a bit more on the OpenGL wiki cleared things up. In this case, the cautious way I program backfired. In my mind, I was attempting to get VBO rendering working, and once I had gotten there, experiment with shaders. I didn't realize I needed to provide some shaders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there are a couple of things that are... odd about this code.

#### First:

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 2);
```

That will never actually draw anything. Triangles are made of 3 vertices and you told it to read 2.

I doubt that's causing the seg-fault, but it might be. Just change the 2 to 3.

#### Next:

```
const float vertexPositions[] = {
  0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f, 0.2f,
  0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 0.2f,
  -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 0.2f,
};
```

Again I'm not sure how you copied that wrong, but the "0.2f" for the W component should be "1.0f".

#### The source of your segfault:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Why do you call this? OK, I know why you're calling it. You've somehow taken a tutorial that's supposed to be showing you how to do modern, shader-based OpenGL, and are adapting it to fixed-function stuff.

If you are, then you need to adapt it *properly*.

`glVertexAttribPointer` is for setting up generic vertex attributes. You *cannot* use generic vertex attributes with fixed-function rendering. If you're going to do things in fixed-function, you need to actually do them in fixed function:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBufferObject);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

Comment: Great reply, I was operating with an incorrect understanding of the distinction between the different rendering methods.

Answer (score 0):

My guess: You have 12 floats for your positions. You are telling to OpenGL that each vertex should be 4 floats by second parameter in here: `glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);`, so you have 3 vertices for these.

Then you tell OpenGL to draw 2 triangles in glDrawArrays command. But this would need 6 vertices - 3 vertices per triangle. So this could cause segmentation fault. Try to draw just one triangle or add more vertices.

Comment: Unless I'm reading it incorrectly, the OpenGL API states that the third argument to glDrawArrays is the number of points to read. Either way, calling `GLDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 1);` results in the same error.

Comment: Maybe you can also check for OpenGL errors. Try to call http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetError.xml after each function call. If it doesn't return some error earlier.

Comment: And also - is that fault in your first draw call or in some other?

Comment: `glGetError` returns GL_NO_ERROR. I'm not sure what your second question was, but the issue happens when I call glDrawArrays.

Comment: Never mind. It was bad idea ;)